# Release build not working when run without debugging in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, build, release

I encountered following problem:

I write program in c++ using VS2010. Debug build works properly when run with/without debugging in VS. When I launch built executable directly it also works.

Release build works when run with debugging in VS and alsp when I launch build executable directly.

Unfortunately, program does not work when I run release build in VS -without debugging-. Window is created and then program crashes quickly (without any error message). Since it crashes when run without debugging I don't know how to identify what causes the problem.

Any ideas what might be causing this? Thanks :)

Comment: So, what is the difference between launching the release-build executable directly through windows explorer and running it without debugging in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems most likely you have some sort of memory error/corruption that just happens to work ok in the debugger.

You can try using couts to isolate how far/where it dies, or try a tool like Purify (or valgrind for free if you can port to Linux).

Comment: Porting to a different OS is a radical, but potentially very effective way of debugging :)

Comment: Thanks, i try the couts :) but what is the difference between launching the .exe directly through windows explorer and running whithout debugging in visual studio? release build does work fine when run directly throught windows explorer.

Comment: @malymato the difference will be in the initialization of memory. If your program is using an uninitialized variable, the default memory contents can cause different behavior.

Comment: Solved, 

it really did turn out that i had uninitialized variable. 

Actually it was ONE bool variable. Program depends on that variable set to true. I forgot to initialize it. When I launched program through VS the variable was initialized to false by VS. So it did not work.

And when I launched the .exe directly, variable was uninitialized, so it contained just a random value, which was of course evaluated to true, so it did work.