# OpenCV 2.4 VideoCapture gets no input from webcam when launched standalone

Tags: opencv, webcam

I am using OpenCV 2.4 in my project to process the images from webcam. Everything works fine in Visual Studio 2010 (both release and debug builds), but when I try to launch exes directly from explorer, the app does not the get input. The camera is started however - it's control LED is on.

Does someone know how to make it work standalone?

I have found something relevant here: 
http://rafaelbarreto.com/2011/06/05/opencv-2-2-webcam-windows-not-working/

and here:
[Can't access webcam with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749498/cant-access-webcam-with-opencv/)

I tried to follow the steps, building OpenCV 2.4 with these prepocessor definitions, but it did not solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: I rebuilt the libs using OpenCV 2.4 tutorial. The Release started to crash afterwards. I checked dependencies with Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and found out that some dll's of OpenCV are targeted for different architectures in the built interestingly enough (some mess in cmakefiles?). I changed some of the dll's so that they match x86 architecture and I was able to run the app, but the initial problem still persist

Comment: The similar problem seems to be solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837070/release-build-not-working-when-run-without-debugging-in-vs2010 . Just checking the code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was, that Visual Studio linked shader sources from somewhere else than during the exectution through IDE.

If the same happens to you, be sure to check it at least four times (I checked 3x).